# javaScript : Line is executing even after return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want a validation check before submitting a user input details to the DB. I have tabs of form and one common separate save button which on click call the save function describe as bellow;

```
$scope.saveFn = function () {
    $("#active_form_id")
        .find("input,textarea,select")
        .each(function (e) {
            var value = $(this).val();
            var id = $(this).prop("id");

            if (value == null || value == "") {
                return false;
                //Abort things here
            }
        });

    alert("After validation check");
}
```

This was called when user hit the save button, And bellow it one endpoint call which saves the data to server.
**My problem is**, even though the `return false` statement is executing, then too my endpoint is getting called and below written alert is executed.

How can i stop executing alert statement?

```
alert("After validation check");
```

Comment: Are you sure that the if-statement is true?

Comment: The code you posted shows nothing after the return false. Code will *never* execute after a return statement within a closure.

Comment: `alert()` is outside of`each()` function so it will always execute.. `return false;` will take you out from `each()` loop not from `$scope.saveFn=function(){`.Also `alert` executes first and then `each()`will start working

Comment: @AlivetoDie _"Also alert executes first and then each()will start working"_ Neither `.find()` nor `.each()` are async - https://jsfiddle.net/n11vjy4k/

Comment: Change `.each()` to `for` loop and use `break`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code. In that I have set one global variable and if validation false set that variable to false

```
var IsValid=true;
 $scope.saveFn = function () {
    $("#active_form_id")
    .find("input,textarea,select")
    .each(function (e) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var id = $(this).prop("id");

        if (value == null || value == "") {
            IsValid=false;
            return false;
            //Abort things here
        }
    });
    if(IsValid){
      alert("After validation check");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what i'm looking for in this moment